# SoundCloud track search without q parameter returns 503

Tags: soundcloud

I think there is an unintended error with the track searching.

I have a desktop app that searches for tracks based on tags. The problem is that without the "q" parameter, no matter what I search for the system returns 503 error.

It worked fine for a year, it only does it recently.
(I can't give you an exact time)

Is this an intended behavior?

Comment: Do you mean the "limit" parameter? As far as I know, the q parameter is your search query. If you don't specify a tag to search for, isn't it logical that it doesn't return results/throws a 503?

Comment: Yes, the _q_ parameter is the searh query, but you can filter based on tags and genre as well. If I want strictly podcast "genre" why would I use the _q_ parameter?
(+ it worked before for a long time)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine, as long as the tag returns a search result:

```
$ curl -sS "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=$client_id&tags=rock&limit=1"  | python -m json.tool | egrep 'tag_list|error_message'
        "tag_list": "korn skrillex kill the noise sonny moore narcissistic cannibal dubstep dance metal rock",

$ curl -sS "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=$client_id&tags=jazz&limit=1"  | python -m json.tool | egrep 'tag_list|error_message'
        "tag_list": "OKeh \"OKeh Records\" Preview Jazz \"new releases\" Brand-new",

$ curl -sS "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=$client_id&tags=barbie&limit=1"  | python -m json.tool | egrep 'tag_list|error_message'
        "tag_list": "\"g.i. joe\" barbie transformers positivity toys video game music vgm nes snes genesis nintendo",

$ curl -sS "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=$client_id&tags=foobar&limit=1"  | python -m json.tool | egrep 'tag_list|error_message'
            "error_message": "503 - Service Unavailable"
```